# Mysqldump not working in jenkins execute shell

Tags: mysql, jenkins

I have a shell script that is running as a cron job, which creates a database dump for backup purposes. When I tried doing the same in a Jenkins execute shell, the following line seems to be giving errors:

```
mysqldump -p thepassword -u theussr --all-databases > databases.sql
```

What happens is that the following error gets into the databases.sql file:

```
Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS]          DB1 [DB2 DB3...]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS]
For more options, use mysqldump --help
```

I am confused as what is going wrong here. I tried with "-r databases.sql" and the file comes out empty with the error being printed in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was the space in -p mypassword, however with removing the space it did not work either.
Finally this helped resolve the issue:

```
export MYSQL_PWD=yourverysecretpassword
mysqldump -u theussr --all-databases > databases.sql
```

Answer (score 4):

For me, this works in Jenkins:

`mysqldump -hxx.xx.xx.xx -pmy_pwd -umy_user db_name > ${filename}`

I am generating the file name with time stamp, like:
`filename=$(date +'%Y%d%m-%H_%M').sql`

Comment: Hey Deepak,
Thanks a lot for your answer. May I ask what is the -hxx.xx.xx.xx option? I can give this a try now..

Comment: yes, but my problem was something else, as mentioned in my own answer